# Getting a 404 with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am hoping somebody can help me with this.

I have a htaccess file in my public html folder for my website with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So when I visit my site to newsletter.html it redirects to domain.co.uk/newsletter instead of domain.co.uk/newsletter.html which is what I want..
 but i also get a 404 saying the page cant be displayed. The webpage in question is named newletter.html in my file manager.

Does anyone know why it cant be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide `.html` extension use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```